Quotient of fibrations
Given a fibration $F\rightarrow E\xrightarrow{p} B$, and suppose there is a subspace $E'\subseteq E$ such that $f|_{E'}:E'\rightarrow B$ is a fibration with fibre $F'\subseteq F$ (assume all inclusions are closed cofibrations). Is there an induced fibration $F/F'\rightarrow E/E'\rightarrow B$? I am not quite sure, as I can't make the homotopy lifting property work, but in e.g. the Serre spectral sequence, one considers the pair of spaces (and if the inclusion of the subspace is a closed cofibration, one can also take the quotient). Furthermore, I am not sure whether one can define a map $E/E'\rightarrow B$ in the first place.
Hence, the question is: ''Does this extend to a space-level version?'' or ''(when) can we turn a relative bundle into a quotient bundle?''
As an example case: For a rank $n$ vector bundle $\xi:E\rightarrow B$, is there a fibration $S^n\rightarrow Th(\xi)\rightarrow B$ on the Thom spaces? (I personally don't think there is even a map $Th(\xi)$ to $B$)
Edit: The goal and motivation is to consider the Serre spectral sequence with $E^2$ page $E_{p,q}^2=H_p(B,h_q(F,F'))$ where $h_*$ is some homology theory. I would like to be able to express this in terms of spectra, meaning if $h_*$ corresponds to the spectrum $T$, I would like to have something of the form $H_p(B;T_q(F/F'))$ as $E^2$ page, without just jumping from $h_*$ to $T$ - but by considering spectra directly (I would like to define it on spectra, not homology theories, like the AHSS - is there an AHSS for relative fibrations?).

It's not hard to see that you cannot have a fibration $S^n \to \mathrm{Th}(\xi) \to B$ in general: Just take $B = S^k$ and $\xi\colon S^k \times \mathbb{R}^n \to S^k$ the trivial bundle. Then the Thom isomorphism tells you that $\tilde{H}^*(\mathrm{Th}(\xi))$ is a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ in degrees $n$ and $n + k$ and zero else, but this is incompatible with the $E_2$-page of the associated Serre spec. seq.: It has a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ in degrees $(n, 0)$, $(0, k)$, and $(n, k)$, so choosing $n$ and $k$ wisely the total space must have non-trivial cohomology in degree $k$ as well.

@BenSteffan Right, that makes sense!

More generally, you shouldn't expect $E/E'$ as the total space of such a fibration unless $B$ is contractible, but a "fiberwise quotient".

That said, there certainly is an AHSS in this setting (though I think 'relative fibration' is ambiguous terminology; there also is a relative AHSS where you fix a subspace of $B$).
